# Probability ( Deck of Cards ).

Tags: probability

Suppose **5** cards are taken at random without replacement from a normal pack of cards. We need to find out the probability of getting exactly **3** of a kind (the other **2** are distinct and are of different kinds).

What I figured out :

$\frac{{{13}\choose{3}} ( Choosing\:3\: cards\: of\: one\: kind ) * {{13}\choose{1}}*{{13}\choose{1}} ( Choosing\: the\: other\: 2\: from\: different\: suits ) \:* \:3 \:*\: 4}{{{52}\choose{5}}}$

But the solution is not correct. What am I doing wrong ?
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Usually, in English, "three of a kind" means three aces, not three spades. $\binom{13}{3}$ computes picking three cards from a suit, not three cards of the same denoination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, in English, "three of a kind" means three aces, not three spades. That is, "kind" means the same denomination (e.g. ace, king, queen,...) not suit (spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs.) Your calculation, using $\binom{13}{3}$ computes picking three cards from a single suit, not three cards of the same denomination.

There are $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}$ ways to pick $3$ cards of the same denomination. There are $\binom{12}{2}\cdot 4\cdot 4$ ways to pick the remaining two cards of differing denominations.

So the probability is:

$$\frac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\cdot \binom{12}{2}\cdot 4\cdot 4}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose a rank from 13 for 3 of a kind
2. Choose 3 cards from 4 of that rank
3. Choose 2 ranks from remaining 12
4. Choose 1 card each from 4 of each of the two ranks
5. Put all of the above together to get favorable ways and divide by total ways, viz. **${52\choose 5}$**